# Does the difficulty level or mode have any effect on available items or story line?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

Fire Emblem has a few different difficulty levels (Normal, Hard and Lunatic) and also a "Classic" and "Casual" mode for permadeath.  Do any of these settings affect item availability, missions, storyline or endings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't change the story in any way but it does change the amount of enemies and the location of them on missions while making them significantly stronger and with different items + skills. The only way to get different storyline is to change your gender during another playthrough and have the characters marry different people. Please note that I haven't finished my Lunatic playthough but haven't seen any differences so far. Also, this is expected as the script writers had TONS of stuff to write already (most of which you will never be able to read), so this is most likely just a gameplay difficulty.

**Spoiler:**
Lucina will have different dialogue with you if you are married to her throughout the game. You can also marry Chrom which will produce a slightly different story.

Comment: Some characters have different stats on higher difficulties. Flavia comes to mind.

Comment: Yeah but the question was asking about a change in story line

Comment: I believe the JP version of Fire Emblem 7 (the first to be released outside of Japan) unlocked an extended ending, if you played on hard and managed to keep every character alive (they also need to be recruited) and if you have linked the game with a savegame from its sequel: Fire Emblem 6 (which explains why this was a JP only feature)